# Objective-c UIImageView Drawing

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, drawing

I have two `UIImageViews`. First one (mainImage) is almost the same size as the view controller. I also have a smaller second one (tempAddImage). What I want to do is to draw the small one's picture on to big one in exactly same place and size. My following code does the job but makes the smaller image full-sized.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.tempAddImage.frame.size);

[self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mainImage.frame.size.width,    
self.mainImage.frame.size.height)
blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

[self.tempAddImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mainImage.frame.size.width, 
self.mainImage.frame.size.height)
blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];

self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

[self.undoArray addObject:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This worked after many tries :) Thanks a lot:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mainImage.frame.size.width, self.mainImage.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    [self.tempAddImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.tempAddImage.frame.origin.x, self.tempAddImage.frame.origin.y - (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 20.0f), self.tempAddImage.frame.size.width, self.tempAddImage.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
    self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.undoArray addObject:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: So you want to overlap the mainImage with tmpImage?

Comment: Yes but lets say mainImage is 300x500 and tmpImage is 150x150. I want to keep the size of tmpImage.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the mainImages frame size in both drawInRects.

Comment: Where should I change exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp"];
UIImageView *tmpImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,tmpImage.size.width, tmpImage.size.height)];
tmpImageView.image = tmpImage;

[mainImg addSubview:tmpImageView];
```

Code not tested..